# I caught a problem when i configed app.config in serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

How to config file app.config in serilog when i want to log in a file with dynamic path.

I used to code like below. But it's not all i need. I need to put "D:\Log" and "Serilog01" in file app.config. I tried to config with add key (below):

but you know, i could't make it dynamic without use 
`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("XXX", "D:\\Log", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`
and `%XXX%` in file app.config

My .cs file:

```
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(now);
            var targetFile = now.Year.ToString() + now.Month.ToString() + now.Day.ToString() + ".txt";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("BASEDIR", "D:\\Log", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PROJNAME", "Serilog01", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TYPE", "INFO", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TARGETFILE", targetFile, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

            //Console.WriteLine()
            // Apply the config to the logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information(info); // info simply is my logger
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

My app.config:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="%BASEDIR%\%PROJNAME%\%TYPE%\%TARGETFILE%" />
```

I hope the file path look like: ``` "BasePath" + "\PROJNAME" + "\TYPE" + "\TARGETFILE", BasePath and PROJNAME from app.config (I don't know how to config that and append it. TYPE and TARGETFILE i'll bring in not use Environment. ..
This is my first time i post in stackoverflow, I hope i can learn more and be helped to solve my problems. Thank~~

Comment: If you know all this at runtime why bother with config files?  Just configure it via code

Comment: This is my mentor'requirement. But can you show me your opinion?. I want to seperate that path like ```"BasePath" + "\PROJNAME" + "\TYPE" + "\TARGETFILE"  ```not a static path like ```"D:\Log\Tag.."```

Comment: Oh. Maybe i don't show exactly my mentor'idea. Can you show how configuration via artifacts vs configuration via code? Difference? and when to use. Thank u!